# Add text inside the Doughnut chart of the React-Chartjs-2 box to react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pie-chart, react-chartjs

I created a Donut chart, which works correctly but now I need to show the number 45 in the center of this, for example.

Where should I indicate the text to be displayed and the coordinates? In the options of the chart?

I'm using react component

```
class DoughnutChart extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const data = {
      datasets: [{
      data: [],
      backgroundColor: [
        '#999',
        '#eee'
      ]
    }],
     text: '45'
  };
    return (
       <Doughnut data={data} />
    );
  }
};

export default DoughnutChart;
```

**EDIT**

I found this plugin, but I cann't find how it applies to the react component

```
//Plugin for center text
Chart.pluginService.register({
  beforeDraw: function(chart) {
    var width = chart.chart.width,
    height = chart.chart.height,
    ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
    ctx.restore();
    var fontSize = (height / 160).toFixed(2);
    ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
    ctx.textBaseline = "top";
    var text = "Foo-bar",
    textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
    textY = height / 2;
    ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
    ctx.save();
  }
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 14):

I tried this and it worked

```js
import { Doughnut } from "react-chartjs-2";

function DoughnutChart() {

 const data = {...}

 const options = {...}

 const plugins = [{
     beforeDraw: function(chart) {
      var width = chart.width,
          height = chart.height,
          ctx = chart.ctx;
          ctx.restore();
          var fontSize = (height / 160).toFixed(2);
          ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
          ctx.textBaseline = "top";
          var text = "Foo-bar",
          textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
          textY = height / 2;
          ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
          ctx.save();
     } 
   }]



  return (
   
        <Doughnut 
          type="doughnut" 
          data={data} 
          options{options} 
          plugins={plugins} 
         />
  );
}

export default DoughnutChart;
```

Comment: I don't know why but your answer fixed text pixilation issue.

Comment: The only thing missing in this answer is id. Please do add 
id: "xyz",
above your beforeDraw function.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe React Chart JS has this option available. However, there are custom plugins out there that allow you to insert custom data labels inside of your doughnut charts. Please refer to this documentation on how to accomplish that.

[ChartJS Plugin Datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/samples/index.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have read about this library and I think it is not possible either. Because I need the value inside the chart.

Comment: I found a plugin that can do this. I just edited my question, could You see it again please?

Answer (score 2):

From what I've seen from [react-chartjs-2](https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2) it only has these properties:

```
data: (PropTypes.object | PropTypes.func).isRequired,
width: PropTypes.number,
height: PropTypes.number,
id: PropTypes.string,
legend: PropTypes.object,
options: PropTypes.object,
redraw: PropTypes.bool,
getDatasetAtEvent: PropTypes.func,
getElementAtEvent: PropTypes.func,
getElementsAtEvent: PropTypes.func
onElementsClick: PropTypes.func, // alias for getElementsAtEvent (backward compatibility)
```

Non of them seem to be text you can pass in to show your number in the middle. You can maybe use the legend prop and manipulate the object created for the legend to move it with css or have another div inside your render that displays the number and then style that to be inside the chart.

Another way you may be able to do it is by wrapping the Doughnut component in a div with another child inside that div that contains the text, like so:

```
    return( 
    <div className='wrapper'> 
        <div className='chart-number'>{this.state.text}</div>
        <Doughnut data={data} />
    </div>)
```

in your css then you will have to figure out how to position the chart-number div in the middle of the wrapper div, which will contain the chart.

If you are just starting to use this library, maybe look for a different one that suits your needs so you don't have to code around it!

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT 1:**

From what I see, you probably need to connect the `Chart.pluginService.register` code to your graph object somehow which is the `<Doughnut />` component, then it will do the calculation before the redraw.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it can be useful. I found a plugin that can do this. I just edited my question, could You see it again please?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution:

**Step 01:** **add this options in your options**

```
options: {
        centerText: {
            display: true,
            text: `90%`
        }
      .....
      .....
```

**Step 02:**   **Create a new method drawInnerText**

```
drawInnerText = (chart) => {

    var width = chart.chart.width,
        height = chart.chart.height,
        ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

    ctx.restore();
    var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
    ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

    var text = chart.config.options.centerText.text,
        textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
        textY = height / 2;

    ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
    ctx.save();
}
```

**Step 03: Invoke drawInnerText**

```
componentWillMount() {
        Chart.Chart.pluginService.register({
            beforeDraw: function (chart) {                    
                if (chart.config.options.centerText.display !== null &&
                    typeof chart.config.options.centerText.display !== 'undefined' &&
                    chart.config.options.centerText.display) {
                    this.drawInnerText(chart);
                }
            },
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function DoughnutChart({ data = {} }) {
 return (
   <Doughnut
     data={format(dataObj)}
     plugins={[
      {
        beforeDraw(chart) {
         const { width } = chart;
         const { height } = chart;
         const { ctx } = chart;
         ctx.restore();
         const fontSize = (height / 160).toFixed(2);
         ctx.font = `${fontSize}em sans-serif`;
         ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
         const { text } = "23";
         const textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2);
         const textY = height / 2;
         ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
         ctx.save();
       },
     },
   ]}
 />);
```

}

Comment: This part is wrong `const { text } = "23";`
Actually it should be like this:
`const text = "bla bla"`

Answer (score 0):

I tried Jays Answer before but nowadays it doesnt work anymore.
You need to specify an id inside the plugins array.

```
 const plugins = [{
 id : 'here comes your id for the specific plugin',
 beforeDraw: function(chart) {
  var width = chart.width,
      height = chart.height,
      ctx = chart.ctx;
      ctx.restore();
      var fontSize = (height / 160).toFixed(2);
      ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
      ctx.textBaseline = "top";
      var text = "Foo-bar",
      textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
      textY = height / 2;
      ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
      ctx.save();
 }
```

}]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Jay answer and at first it did not work so I had to make some updates to it and now it is working.

```
const plugins = {[
{
  id:"Id here",
  beforeDraw:function(chart:any) {
    let ctx = chart.ctx;
    let xAxis = chart.scales.x;
    let yAxis = chart.scales.y;
    let maxValue = Math.max(...chart.data.datasets[0].data);
    let minValue = Math.min(...chart.data.datasets[0].data);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.font = '14px Roboto';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.textAlign = 'left';
    ctx.fillText('Text1 = ', xAxis.left , yAxis.top + 15);
    ctx.fillText('Text2 = ', xAxis.left , yAxis.top + 40);
    ctx.fillText(maxValue + 'Â°C', xAxis.left + 200, yAxis.top + 15);
    ctx.fillText(minValue + 'Â°C', xAxis.left + 200, yAxis.top + 40);
    ctx.restore();
 },
```

},
]}